# Post build event command line - not working

Tags: visual-studio-2012

In my ASP.NET web application, I am trying to copy the common configuration file 'application.Common.dll.config' to WebUI project's 'Web.config' location.

The below lines were in Post build event command line section in project properties and they are not working. Am I missing anything?

```
Copy /Y "$(SolutionDir)Common\bin\$(ConfigName)\application.Common.dll.config" "$(SolutionDir)WebUI\Web.config"
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should not use $(ConfigName). Instead, it should be $(ConfigurationName). Try with $(ConfigurationName) and let us know if you still have issue,=